# How to properly space tikz button in a vertical column

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to vertically space buttons in a single column with equal distance between them. I don't understand what I am doing wrong in this MWE.  Any guidance is much appreciated!

NOTE:  I have updated the MWE below so that it now achieves my desired goal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{
  fit, shapes, automata, backgrounds, positioning, shadows, patterns, calc,
  arrows.meta,
  shapes.geometric
}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfhighlight=/N}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let \n0={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}},
                \n1={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}},
                \p1=([shift={(\n0, -\n1)}] sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=([shift={(-\n0, \n1)}] sourcenode.south east),
                \n2={\x2-\x1},
                \n3={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north west, at=(\p1)] {\href{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n2}{\n3}}}}}
        }
    },
}

\def\testurl{https://google.com}

\vspace{2cm}

\foreach \j\k in {Button 1/\testurl, Button 2/\testurl, Button 3/\testurl, Button 4/\testurl}
{
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[button/.style={fit={(0cm,0cm) (4.3cm,1cm)}, fill=blue, draw=none, drop shadow, text=white, rounded corners=0.5cm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, label=center:\textcolor{white}{\large\textsc{\j}}}]
  \node[button, hyperlink node=\k] at (0cm, 0cm) {};
\end{tikzpicture}\par
\vspace{1cm}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add `\noindent` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\newline` after `\end{tikzpicture}` they are vertical and centered although the distance between them is not great: https://imgur.com/a/RvtfkN0

Comment: I think because you are using `article` then the normal rules apply about new paragraphs being indented etc

Comment: @JamesT Thanks for  your  quick response! I will try your suggestion. In the meantime, by chance do you know why the absolute x,y coordinates in the \node command are not being honored? In other words, how do I control the  spacing between the buttons?

Comment: No worries, to be honest I am still learning `tikz` myself but I am pretty confident someone more experienced will be able to answer this soon, is an interesting question

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not place all four nodes in one TikZ picture to position them to your liking? You can use `\par` after each picture to start a new paragraph. You could place them in a `tabular`. All TikZ pictures are independent of each other and their position on the page. Your `at (0cm, -\i cm)` doesn't do anything since the nodes are the only content of each TikZ picture. The coordinate system is local to each TikZ picture.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for the quick response.  I am just trying to list those  buttons in a vertical column about 1cm apart.  I just swapped out the ```\newline``` command for the  ```\par``` command and that solved my problem.  Thanks for the info regarding the  relative coordinate system of each TikZ picture!